# Get id of clicked element inside a div with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a page with a menu. That menu is surrounded by a div id="tools". I pass the tools div to an EventHandler. That Evenyhandler should figure on which entry in the menu the user clicked that the program can continue due to the userchoice.

In JQuery I would do something like this

```
  $(document).click(function (event) {
        var text = $(event.target).text();
        if (text.contains("line")) {
            //DO
        } else if (text.contains("square")) {
            //DO
        }
    });
```

If I use event.target in typescript I have no option to extract the content.

It can be displayed with console.log(event.target) but thats it.

So how can I please get the content of the target?

```
<div>
    <div id="tools" style="position: fixed; top: 200px; left: 800px">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="line">Line</a></li>
            <li><a id="circle">Circle</a></li>
            <li><a id="triangle">Triangle</a></li>
            <li><a id="square">Square</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
 menu.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        //relevant part for my question
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast `event` to `HTMLElement` like this

`var text = (<HTMLElement>evt.target).textContent;`